# Fractional part is removed after load data from Teradata to Spark

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark, teradata

We're trying to load data from Teradata, the code using is:

```
sparkSession.read
      .format("jdbc")
      .options(
        Map(
          "url" -> "jdbc:teradata://hostname, user=$username, password=$password",
          "MAYBENULL" -> "ON",
          "SIP_SUPPORT" -> "ON",
          "driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver",
          "dbtable" -> $table_name
        )
      )
      .load()
```

However, some data lost its fractional part after loading. To be more concise, the column in Teradata is in the type of [Number][1] and after loading, the data type in Spark is `DecimalType(38,0)`, the scale value is 0 which means no digits after decimal point.

Data in Teradata is something like,

```
id column1 column2
1   50.23    100.23
2   25.8     20.669
3   30.2     19.23
```

The `dataframe` of Spark is like,

```
id column1 column2
1   50     100
2   26     21
3   30     19
```

The meta data of the table in Teradata is like:

```
CREATE SET TABLE table_name (id BIGINT, column1 NUMBER, column2 NUMBER) PRIMARY INDEX (id);
```

The Spark version is 2.3.0 and Teradata is 16.20.32.59.

So here comes question, why the automatic conversion happens and how can I keep the data's fractional part in Spark just as it was in Teradata.
[1]: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Data-Types-and-Literals/June-2017/Numeric-Data-Types/FLOAT/REAL/DOUBLE-PRECISION-Data-Types

Comment: NUMBER gets mapped to java.math.BigDecimal but it seems that "unbounded" NUMBER is mapped to (38,0). You may need to use a SELECT query rather than a table name so you can CAST the column to a NUMBER type with specific scale, or perhaps to DECIMAL or FLOAT if that's more appropriate.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for the comment, it could be a workaround. The original type in Teradata is Number without explicit scale setting. So I can't cast it to a decimal type with correct scale setting. If wrong scale set, the number convert exception is thrown. Anyway, it's proved that convert Number to double/float is workable, it could be a workaround if the precision missing (double/float can't hold as much fractional digits as Number/Decimal does) is tolerated.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/36499), the Spark 3.4.0 will respect the scale info of Teradata Number Type.